# Controller method never gets executed although view is rendered fine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, controllers

I have a strange problem with my Rails routing . 
I have a controllers called Page and a method called Page#dashboard

When I try to access /dashboard/1  the dashboard method of Page Controller never gets executed. 
But surprisingly the /pages/dashboard.html.erb is rendered fine .

Can someone explain me why ?

Code details as below . Thanks

Trying to access - `/dashboard/1`

Routes.rb

```
match '/dashboard/:id' => 'page#dashboard'
```

Page_Controller.rb

```
class PageController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :init

  private

  def init

    puts "init getting executed !!!!!!!!!"  #this gets printed on console

  end

  def dashboard

     puts "dashboard getting executed !!!!!!!!!" #this doesnt get printed on console


  end

end
```

viewPage - Pages/dashboard.html.erb

The logs are shown as below -

```
init getting executed !!!!!!!!!
Started GET "/dashboard/8" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-06-03 00:04:40 +0800
Processing by PageController#dashboard as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"8"}
  Rendered page/dashboard.html.erb within layouts/page (45.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 180ms (Views: 133.6ms | ActiveRecord: 3.1ms)
```

Comment: Have you tried to pass the `id` parameter that you have setted on your `routes.rb` ?

Comment: Yes. I am trying to access /dashboard/1 . Shouldnt that make id=1 ?

Comment: whats the error message? and could you paste your `routes.rb` file?

Comment: There is no error . Just that the code inside the dashboard method doesnt get executed. I added the logs to the question .

Comment: What if the dashboard method isn't private?

Comment: Thanks @Dave Newton. I wasnt aware that adding private to a method made all the methods below it also private. I just amended it and it works fine . Thanks a lot .

Comment: You're not adding it "to a method" is why ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, you don't have to define an action method. If all you want to do is render a template then as long as the template `foo` exists, rails will happily allow you to route to SomeController#foo.

Secondly, for a method to be an action is has to be public. Your dashboard method is private so it doesn't count as an action and doesn't get executed. Since you have a dashboard.html.erb template, rails does however render that.

Comment: Thanks . I just deleted the contents of my dashboard while posting here method to make the question simple and clear . However the second paragraph of your answer does answer my question . I wasnt aware that adding private to a method made all the methods below it also private. I just amended it and it works fine . Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If you are upgrading a rails app and have old-style 'before_filter' calls in the controller, these need to be changed to 'before_action'. The 'before_filter' calls will crash and bypass the controller, but the template will still render with no errors.